# watchOS update apparent failure

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

I am having problems updating to build 13S5325c, although all installations have worked fine previously.

After following both procedures as set out by Apple:

- mailing the downloaded configuration profile to the iPhone and installing from there
- downloading directly through Safari on the phone

the profile shows in the Apple Watch App > General > Profiles.

On tapping Install, all seems as it should be, the only suspicious point being that Apple's docs state that there will be an Apple Logo and progress bar while installation takes place. Instead I see the activity indicator for a second or two.

Then I am offered a restart of the watch, which I select.

When the restart is done, I still see build 13S5305d.

I have checked that I am downloading the most recent profile. I am using iOS 9 build 13A4325c. The watch is charged and attached to the charger.

Answer (score 0):

Worked when installing after 'new version available' badge appeared, i.e. without recourse to the developer website page.